# bash replacing value of column with another one

Tags: bash

I have a file with applications and their version number. And I want to change their version from an automated script. Here is a sample of the file

```
bm_app:2.2.9
sm_app:7.0.5
```

Now I've a variable which stores the new version of bm_app.

```
echo $fg
5.7.8
```

Now when I try to replace the version of bm_app using this variable like this, a zero is appended to the minor part of the version as shown below.

```
grep bm LATEST_APP_VERSION.md | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"'$fg'}'
bam_app:5.70.8
```

Now I don't want the unecessary zero to be appended to my output. I tried the "printf" to format it, but didn't succeed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Ashutosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v var=$fg -F: '/bm/ {print $1":"var}' filename
```

Pass you variable to awk with -v and use a regular expression to search for bm entries within awk as opposed to using grep.

Comment: thanks alot. It worked flawlessly. Do you have any idea why there was a zero appended in my awk command? It would be good to know why awk behaved that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the -v awk flag to pass in your variable.

Example use:

```
#!/bin/bash
BM="bm_app:2.2.9"
fg="5.7.8"
echo $BM | awk -v x=$fg -F ':' '{print $1":"x}'
```

Output:

```
bm_app:5.7.8
```

Answer (score 1):

With single ***sed*** command:

```
sed 's/\(bm_app:\).*/\1'"$fg"'/' LATEST_APP_VERSION.md
```

The output:

```
bm_app:5.7.8
sm_app:7.0.5
```